# vba import from web html element(price)

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I would like to import from a website the Ethereum price to Excel with VBA.

```
Sub go()
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .navigate "https://www.coingecko.com/de/munze/ethereum.html"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set getPrice = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("span.currency-exchangable")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = getPrice.innerText

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

Range("B1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

I have also activated under References the `Microsoft Internet Control`, `Microsoft Object HTML Library` and `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 library`.

The error message is

> Run time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

I only want to import the price of Ethereum = $1,371.43

Comment: You might like to fix the typo - is `exchanggable` really the way it is spelled?  (I have no idea whether any of the rest of the code makes sense - just that typos like that will definitely break things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following.

Note:

The link I provide at the end gives preference to `XMLHTTP60` over Internet Explorer to retrieve HTML. Certainly was faster in my experience.

Also, do not use the reserved word `Go` for a procedure name. It will throw an error.

You need to access by class name.

```
Sub Testing()
'ms html library reference
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .navigate "https://www.coingecko.com/de/munze/ethereum.html"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLDoc = appIE.Document

Dim HTMLItemCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set HTMLItemCol = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("currency-exchangable")

Dim myValue As String
myValue = HTMLItemCol.Item(1).innerText

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

Reference: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 47 - Browsing to Websites and Scraping a Web Page](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzL_0nIe8B4-7ShhVPfJkgw)

With adding a reference to Microsoft XML library here is a faster way to retrieve the info:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

'MS XML

Dim xmlpage As New XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument

xmlpage.Open "GET", "https://www.coingecko.com/de/munze/ethereum.html", False 'requires well formed URL
xmlpage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlpage.responseText

Dim HTMLItemCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set HTMLItemCol = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("currency-exchangable")

Dim myValue As String
myValue = HTMLItemCol.Item(1).innerText

ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

Comment: I gave you the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get the price:

```
Sub fetch_price()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim getprice As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.coingecko.com/de/munze/ethereum.html"
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Set getprice = html.getElementsByClassName("currency-exchangable")(1)
    [A1] = getprice.innerText
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls
```

Using `xmlhttp` request. It is way faster than IE but something goes wrong with the number format. I used `queryselector` to avoid hardcoded index.

```
Sub fetch_price()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim getprice As Object

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://www.coingecko.com/de/munze/ethereum.html", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set getprice = html.querySelector(".coin-value span[class='currency-exchangable']")
    [A1] = getprice.innerText
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft XML, v6.0 'or the version you have
```

Comment: Well i will give you +1 for that!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about ".coin-value span[class='currency-exchangable']"

Comment: Yeah sure. I used css selector to be more specific about the value I'm after. It is sometimes difficult to deal with if we choose the option for `queryselectorAll`. However, In this case `queryselector` is very handy to go with. Here is how the css selectors can be defined: [Link_to_css_selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.